# facebook login to website with only javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

is that even possible?

What I'm currently doing is using [this](http://pastie.org/3547251) code wherein after line 37 I intend to setup a cookie of my own indicating who is logged in and then redirect the browser to another page. But I think that's not secure since user can look into javascript and mess with the cookie. But isn't that what fb js sdk must be doing behind the scene, setting some cookie?

How can I securely log in a user into my website(I will be maintaining a db table of fb ids)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You no need to set separate cookie when you are using fb login as your authentication and data(fb uid).

But still am bit confused with what exactly u ve to do. As far as i understood, 
if login
u want to redirect the user to some other page
else 
show him login button

is it correct??

Then do this:

1) Have custom login button instead of FBML login button(make it invisible first).

2) in setup() method if the "*response.status*" is connected then redirect
else show login button - onclick of button call FB.login() http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/
this will do the login and authentication of ur site.

3) Subscribe to "*auth.statusChange*" instead "*auth.login*" http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/
so when the user status changes, it will invoke your setup() method

This should solve your problem.

Cheers

Comment: Fb.login has to be called explicitly?? 

and how will my website's server side know which user is this?

Comment: You will get UID in the 'response.authResponse.userID' once he is logged in. UID should be a primary key in ur DB

Comment: Once your authentication is done, redirect him to page u want to show him. and also u ll have that user's UID. Using UID u will know who is logged in.

Comment: Okay, but suppose I redirect to page2 and pass the uid as get parameter. Then can't a `malicious` user open the page2 with uid parameter of his choice? I mean is this way secure?

Comment: any answer to my last comment? Yours was the only answer so I accepted it. :)